# Render a DetailsList component with all items preselected

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I want to render a `DetailsList` with all items in that list preselected. I pass a `Selection` prop to the `DetailsList`, but calling `setAllSelected()` on the Selection from the component's constructor won't render all items as selected.

- Though, calling `setAllSelected()` from an event handler would select all items as expected.
- I have tried to call `setAllSelected()` from `componentDidMount()`, but without success.
- I suppose items must be internally created  (wrt the `DetailsList` component) before the `Selection` can select them, but I have no idea how to force this.

I have added a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bmarcot/pen/WBYaPp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the items on the selection first like so:

```
this._selection.setItems(this.state.items, false)
```

I adjusted your codepen [here](https://codepen.io/vitalius1/pen/joXbWa) to demo this. Hope this helps.